# Haskell argument application through '$x' in 'map' to a list of inflix operator functions. How does it work?

Tags: list, haskell, optimization, functional-programming, map-function

I would just like to know, out of curiosity pertaining to how this functions, is the intermediary expression below resulting from some sort of optimization? I do understand that the $ is actually a function, which is being supplied only with one argument. Somehow, through application of this function to a function from the list provided by 'map', it manages to see that '$' function is lacking precisely a function, which as I mentioned is provided by 'map'. Is this optimization behavior something unique to function application with '$'? Because, for what its worth I cannot see it how this would follow from the function definitions of 'map' and '$', which I provide for convenience below.

From an outset, it seems that the '$3' should emerge before the function expressions, but such expressions will not evaluate in compiler. Here is the expanded intermediary expression of the optimization, that is seemingly taking place:

```
[(4+) $3, (10*) $3, (^2) $3, sqrt $3]
```

definition - $

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b  
f $ x = f x
```

definition - map

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]  
map _ [] = []  
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

example used

```
map ($ 3) [(4+), (10*), (^2), sqrt]
```

returned result

```
[7.0,30.0,9.0,1.7320508075688772]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are wondering what happens if you write `($ 3)`?

Haskell syntax has a concept called "[***Section of an infix operator***](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator)". It means that if you write an expression with an operator (here `+`), then:

```
(2 +) == \x -> 2 + x == (+) 2
(+ 2) == \x -> x + 2 == flip (+) 2
```

Haskell is a *functional* programming language. One of the aspects of a functional programming language is that you can take functions as parameters. This is not limited to functional programming languages: in Java, C#, C++, etc. you can pass function/method references to functions/methods, and for instance call these functions with parameters.

So you have written:

```
map (\x -> ($) x 3) [(4+), (10*), (^2), sqrt]
```

and `\x -> ($) x 3` is just an ordinary function. So if we apply this to the first argument, we get:

```
(\x -> ($) x 3) (4+)
-> ($) (4+) 3
-> (4+) 3
-> 4 + 3
-> 7
```

So there is nothing special with the `($ 3)` case, it works with any operator where we only fill in the right hand side of the operator.

In fact you already used that concept with `(^2)` as well. Your list actually looks like:

```
map (flip ($) 3) [(+) 4, (*) 10, flip (^) 2, sqrt]
```

So you used sectioning - both left and right - in the elements of the list.

Comment: and there's sensible elegance in the explanation. i truly appreciate you taking the time!